# update-grub shows "No volume groups found"

Tags: grub2, bootloader

Whenever I run `sudo update-grub` in a terminal, I get the following output:

```
    Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-1-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.0.0-1-amd64
  No volume groups found
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

What could have caused this, and what can I do to fix it?